# CSS Transition delay, but tapping fixes it?

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I've been trying to figure this one out, but need some help from the experts:

The project is HTML/CSS/jQuery in Phonegap running on Android 4.2.2. I have a div that expands from 10% width to 90% width when clicked. About 3/4s through the transition, it will get stuck and after a second it will finish - or if you tap the screen it will finish. This is just a simple, background colored div with barely any text in it.

The other funny issue is that on a separate page, I have a range slider that updates the contents of a DIV onchange. If you drag it on the touchscreen, there will be a delay between it updating the value (but if you tap the screen anywhere else, it will update the value instantly).

```
$('#region').click(function() { 
  if ($('#section').hasClass('expanded')) { 
    $('#section').removeClass('expanded'); 
    console.log('minimized'); 
  }
  else { 
    $('#section').addClass('expanded'); 
    console.log('expanded'); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please ask only **one** question per post, and include code where necessary -- such as here.

Comment: Thanks! The following is the code for the transitions:
$('#region').click(function() {
     if ($('#section').hasClass('expanded')) {
       $('#section').removeClass('expanded');
       console.log('minimized');
       } else {
     $('#section').addClass('expanded');
     console.log('expanded');
     }
    })